# .NET Framework 4.5 installed but not found in regedit

Tags: .net-framework, .net-4.5

I just installed .NET Framework 4.5 and restarted the system. It shows installed in control panel but could not find in registry.

[image]

[image: reg 1]

[image: reg 2]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve in other words what problem does the missing key cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're looking in the wrong place.

Taken from [the article “How to Determine which .NET Framework versions
are installed”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at Microsoft Docs:

> To find the installed .NET Framework versions manually (versions 4.5 and later):
>
> 1. On the **Start** menu, choose **Run**.
> 2. In the **Open** box, enter **regedit.exe**.
>      You must have administrative credentials to run regedit.exe.
> 3. In the Registry Editor, open the following subkey:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
>    ```
>
>    Note that the path to the `Full` subkey
>      includes the subkey `Net Framework` rather than `.NET Framework`.
>
>    > #### Note
>    >
>    > If the `Full` subkey is not present,
>    >     then you do not have the .NET Framework 4.5 or later installed.
>
>    Check for a DWORD value named `Release`. 
>      The existence of the `Release` DWORD indicates that the .NET Framework 4.5 or newer has been installed on that computer.
>
>    The registry entry for the .NET Framework 4.5.
>
>    The value of the Release DWORD indicates which version of the .NET Framework is installed.

```
Value of the Release DWORD:        Version

378389                          .NET Framework 4.5

378675                          .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed with Windows 8.1
                                 or Windows Server 2012 R2

378758                          .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed on Windows 8, Windows 7 SP1,
                                 or Windows Vista SP2

379893                          .NET Framework 4.5.2

On Windows 10 systems: 393295   .NET Framework 4.6 
On all other OS versions: 393297

On Windows 10                   .NET Framework 4.6.1 
   November Update systems: 394254
On all other OS versions: 394271

On Windows 10                   .NET Framework 4.6.2 
   Anniversary Update: 394802
On all other OS versions: 394806

On Windows 10                   .NET Framework 4.7 
    Creators Update: 460798
On all other OS versions: 460805

On Windows 10                   .NET Framework 4.7.1 
   Fall Creators Update: 461308
On all other OS versions: 461310
```

Answer (score 0):

emaillenin is looking in the correct place.  The registry key Kryten mentioned does not always exist on Server 2012 R2: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"

No explanation from Microsoft why there is a difference.  The Release DWORD is not available when the registry key does not have the "NET Framework Setup" path.

Comment: If “emaillenin is looking in the correct place”, why isn’t there anything there?